# jQuery timing SetInterval

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, synchronization

Ok, So I'm apparently missing something here. I know this comes back to the synch/asynch thing, but I can't figure it out.

I'm trying to build an image carousel that slides a row of images to the left on hover and stops sliding when hover is over.

The general logic for the slider goes something like this:

Default state: there are a bunch of images floated left next to each other extending past the edge of the viewport:
( Hash signs are the viewport)

**#** [ IMAGE-1 ] [ IMAGE-2 ] **#** [ IMAGE-3 ]

I use animate to give IMAGE-1 a negative margin, pulling it out of the viewport.

[ IMAGE-1 ] **#** [ IMAGE-2 ] [ IMAGE-3 ] **#**

I would then move IMAGE-1 to the end of the sequence, set it's margin back to 0, and do it again.

**#** [ IMAGE-2 ] [ IMAGE-3 ] **#** [ IMAGE-1 ]

So my problem is, IMAGE-1 is getting moved to the end of the sequence before the animation finishes. I assume what's happening is that the "animate" function and the bit that moves image-1 are firing at the same time. I would like to issue these commands in order, so that when one finishes, the other begins.

Here is my function:

```
function slideLoop(div) {
    var width = div.find("img:first").width();
    var i = setInterval(function(){
        var images = div.find("img");
        var first = images.first();
        images.last().css("marginLeft", 0);
        first.animate({marginLeft: 0 - width + "px"}, 4000, "linear");
        images.last().after(images.first());
    }, 4000);
}
```

Thanks In advance.

Comment: looks like you want to use animate callback function instead of a interval

Comment: Please provide a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). It helps other users to see your script in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @roasted says, you need to register the actions in the callback function, `animate` sets everything up, but returns without waiting for the animaton to happen:

```
function slideLoop(div) {
    var width = div.find("img:first").width();
    var i = setInterval(function(){
        var images = div.find("img");
        var first = images.first();
        images.last().css("marginLeft", 0);
        first.animate({marginLeft: 0 - width + "px"}, 4000, "linear",function(){
            images.last().after(images.first());
        });
    }, 4000);
}
```